# MVVM, Threading and Image Source DataBinidng

Tags: wpf, multithreading, image, mvvm

I have an MVVM implementation in which I have a WPF ListBox that will contain a collection of child WPF Image controls. The Source for each control may change as often as 3 times per second.  When I have just a single image in my list, life is grand and my app is responsive.  When I start having 4 or 5 my application child images, my app starts grinding, I should also mention that I have to a Bitmap to BitmapSource conversion for each new and or updated image that I have.

How should I update my children controls Source property while keeping my application as responsive as possible?

Here is the current code in my ViewModel:

```
public BitmapSource CameraBitmapSource
    {
        get
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
                    {
                        BuildImageSource();
                    }, DispatcherPriority.Background);

            return this.cameraBitmapSource;
         }
    }
```

BuildImageSource() is where I fetch my new bitmap and convert to a BitmapSource and then assign to my private cameraBitmapSource object.

Comment: WPF is not a good choice for animation. You're trying to use a wrench to pound nails

Comment: @Jay: I'm not sure this is accurate.  This method of animation, by updating an image property through databinding, I agree with you.  But WPF directly supports other types of animation via storyboards, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`, you're doing all the work on the UI thread, which makes your app unresponsive. You should build the images on a separate thread. The easiest way to do that is to make the binding asynchronous, and call your `BuildImageSource` method directly.

**ViewModel**

```cs
public BitmapSource CameraBitmapSource
{
    get
    {
        BuildImageSource();
        return this.cameraBitmapSource;
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Image Source="{Binding CameraBitmapSource, IsAsync=True}" />
```

Just remember to `Freeze` the `ImageSource` in `BuildImageSource` so that it can be used on the UI thread (`DependencyObjects` can only be used on the thread that created them, unless they're `Freezable` and frozen)